# XNA - Saving Game Data without TypeWriter?

Tags: xna, xna-content-pipeline

In the past, I've had some trouble with reading and writing content for XNA. I think I'm firmly set on [this tutorial](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/content-pipeline-extension-1) which sets up a four project structure (Game, Content, Library, Pipeline Extension) for the solution that other websites suggest, too. The options it offers for content reading seem great.

But problem! This tutorial (and all others I've found) have stated that the Content Pipeline Extension Project is not distributed with the game, which is fine in itself, but this is combined with the fact that any content *writing* objects are placed in this non-distributable library. The ability to actually write content of an already existing type (save game files, namely) is pretty critical to the project I'm trying to make.

I've already learned the hard way you simply can't place the Content Pipeline reference in another project besides the extension for easier access to the intermediate deserializer. Is there another object I can access for writing save game data? Am I actually, despite the warnings of this tutorial, able to use the TypeWriter outside of the Content Pipeline Extension Project? Or is there a third option I am missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Content Pipeline is not for your game's save data. What the Content Pipeline does is allow you to import assets (whether it be sounds, textures, models, XML files, or whatnot) to your project and compile them into an efficient format for distribution with your game. It may seem like this is somehow limiting, but having this easy-to-use unified framework for handling asset compilation is a huge deal.

The way you save game files on XNA is via the storage API in the [`Microsoft.XNA.Framework.Storage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.storage.aspx) namepsace. On XBLIG, these classes handle saving data to memory cards or the Xbox hard drive. On Windows, this typically saves to the user's `%APPDATA%` or a similar location (the specifics are in the docs).

If you're targeting Windows, you also have the option of using file I/O to save and load data. Look at the [`System.IO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29kt2zfk.aspx) namespace, and more specifically, the [`File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) class within that namespace.

Comment: Ah, that makes things so much easier. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

All XNA platforms have support (some partial) for the System.IO class. To save data using XNA, you can either use isolated storage or the XNA storage system (or just default System.IO on windows). Those will give you an IO stream which you will then use the System.IO classes to write with. (BinaryWriter, StreamWriter, etc.)